# catch exception when calling an element and try again (page factory)

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch

I'm using a page factory and AjaxElementLocatorFactory in my selenium project. Each component object extends this class:

```
public abstract class AbstractComponent {

    public AbstractComponent(WebDriver driver){
        AjaxElementLocatorFactory factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 5);
        PageFactory.initElements(factory, this);
    }
}
```

In order to make my tests more stable, I want to implement try and catch Each time I call an element in page factory, so if selenium throws an exception of any kind (like StaleElementReferenceException or ElementNotInteractableException), it will try again for a few seconds.

I'm looking to implement something like this (with timeout):

```
while(true) {
        try {
            this.element.click();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I need a general solution that will work each time I use an element in the page factory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should make your factory return extended `AjaxElementLocator` where you override `protected boolean isElementUsable(WebElement element)` which returns `true` by default.

Unless the condition is not true the locator will be taking new attempts to lookup element. So no extra code in your page class will be required.

The exceptions are caught and re-tried inside `AjaxElementLocator`. This is basically how it is different from a regular locator.

You can find some details [here](https://webelement.click/en/selenium_page_object_expected_conditions).

Basically the above should be enough to make your code stable since in order to make your test stable you should understand which conditions define the UI ready for taking the test.

However if you need to add some retry functionality (but note that stale element won't ever get back to a normal state) you need to add some changes to the following structure:

1. Extend `DefaultFieldDecorator` class. There is *protected* method `proxyForLocator` which defines the logic of creating a proxy pbject for your field. In that default implementation there is the line `InvocationHandler handler = new LocatingElementHandler(locator);` where `new LocatingElementHandler(locator);` is responsible for handling calls to page field and dispatching it to a real object.
2. Extend `LocatingElementHandler` so that it calls a super method but try-catch and reties if needed.
3. In overridden method of `DefaultFieldDecorator` change old handler to your custom one.
4. When you initialize your page use the code like this:

```java
public YourPageClass(SearchContext context) {
    PageFactory.initElements(
            new CustomFieldDecorator(
                    new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(context)
            ), this
    );
}
```

The approach above would let you to change one place (actually two: Field Decorator and Invocation Handler) but cover all possible exception which can appear when acting with already located element.

Comment: What kind of code? OP does not mention which condition they'd like to await. Just catching and re-trying is the default behavior of `AjaxElementLocator`. If you need some details let me know which exactly. I'll add code example.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but to my knowledge AjaxElementLocator catching and retrying only if the element wasn't located. Once the element is located, but click it throws ElementClickInterceptedException or StaleElementReferenceException,  AjaxElementLocator won't try again. So I'll appreciate it if you could add the code that catches those two exceptions with timeout. Thank You!

Comment: For catching StaleElementReferenceException each time I call the click() function in WebElement, is it enough to extend the AjaxElementLocator? Or I should use your second solution? Thanks!

Comment: The second should help.

Comment: Not sure where exactly I need to add my try and catch. Which method I need to override in MyLocatingElementHandler? What confuses me is that to my knowledge what throws the exceptions I mentioned isn't the FindElement fucntion, but the click() function in the WebElement class. so how override the locating handler helps? Thank You!

Comment: You should override method `invoke` of `LocatingElementHandler` so that the code would be pretty much the same as the base one but you need to wrap `method.invoke(element, objects);` with retry mechanism. If you need more details with example I think I will be able to provide one in a day or two.